# Reformat code style in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style

I'm looking for an automatic way in eclipse to reformat curly braces to K&R style, eliminating braces for single statements if, etc. Is there such a way?

Thanks.

Comment: *eliminating braces for single statements if* : very bad idea IMO! I'd strongly advice to follow Sun's conventions instead.

Comment: It's for a homework assignment in minimal programming practices 
(Spartan Programming).

Comment: I don't think that is possible in eclipse. And there is a reason for that :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before you reformat you need to customize the formatter settings in the Preferences Dialog `Java/ Code Style / Formatter` to your K&R settings if the default settings don't match your requirements.

The Preferences Dialog is opened from `Mainmenu / Window / Preferences`

You can even configure a save action `Java / Editor / Save Action` to format source code on save.

Comment: Is there an option to disable braces in one-liners ifs?

Comment: No I don't think so code is formated but not changed, anyway the edit dialog has so many options.

Comment: You can remove braces in simple statements with using Source/Clean Up... (you have to configure it in preferences - in the Code Style page set 'Use blocks in if/while/for/do statements' to 'Only if necessary'). Also you can do this kind of clean up as a save action as well). However you cannot do this only for if-s but not while-s.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of options for formatting can be chosen in the preferences dialog (Java -> Code Style -> Formatter).

After that, you can simply format your code by pressing ctrl-shift-f (windows)

Also, you can choose to automatically format your code whenever you save your file. This is also in the preferences dialog (Java -> Editor -> Save Actions)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize how Java code is formatted going to `Window > Preferences`. There, choose `Java > Code Style > Formatter`, click on `New...` to create a new profile. Then `Edit...` it.

However, I'm quite sure Eclipse's code formatter **won't add or remove braces**, it will simply position them according to your style rules. You will need a separate tool to do this or a fancy search and replace.

Answer (score 0):

right click in your editor  => source => format